# Apache2 - default php7.2-fpm.conf has to be included in every virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I'm trying to move from mod_php to php-fpm using mod_proxy_fcgi.

After installing the needed modules I tried following the notice I got during install:

> Not enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default.
>
> To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in Apache2 do:
>
> a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
>
> a2enconf php7.2-fpm

After doing that and restarting Apache my website served me the php files as plain text.

Only after adding `Include conf-enabled/php7.2-fpm.conf` to my virtual host configuration file (after setting up letsencrypt I have two for all of my virtual hosts and it had to be added to both).

I'm a bit reluctant to do that - in the future `php7.2-fpm.conf` will probably move to `php7.3-fpm.conf` and I have to add touch all the configuration files again.

This is the content of `php7.2-fpm.conf`:

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the
        # files only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

So I'm wondering is there a way to change the behavior that the php-fpm mechanism works without touching all of my virtual host configuration files?

Comment: Have you restarted the server after enabling the modules and configuration?

Comment: @Okneloper yes I did that. Currently I'm running with a workaround: I have created a `php-fpm.conf` which includes the `php7.2-fpm.conf` and the `php-fpm.conf` gets included in every page. So if the name changes I only have to touch the `php-fpm.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must only use the ExecCGI option in your virtual hosts.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```